# Adding 1 more field breaks PHP Contact Form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Everything was working fine until I added in the field for the phone number. If I remove it, the email gets sent.

I did type = 'tel' but it didn't work either. I tried any variations I could find to troubleshoot the problem and the only thing that works consistently is removing all traces of the phone field from html and php.

HTML:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Phone" name="phone" placeholder="PhoneNumber">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Message" required="requried"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-block" >Send</button>
</form>
```

PHP (Snippet):

```
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $clientemail = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $phone = (stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $clientemail . "\n\n" . 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

     $email = new PHPMailer();      

    $email->From      = $clientemail;
    $email->FromName  = $name;
    $email->Subject   = 'Message from Website User';//$subject;
    $email->Body      = $body;  
    $email->AddAddress( 'johndoe@gmail.com' ); //Send to this email

 // EXPLICITLY TELL PHP-MAILER HOW TO SEND THE EMAIL... IN THIS CASE USING PHP BUILT IT MAIL FUNCTION    
        $email->isMail();

    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);

 // NOW, TRY TO SEND THE EMAIL ANYWAY:
        try{
            $success    = $email->send();
            $status['type']    = 'success';
            $status['message']  = 'Thank you for contacting us. We will reply as soon as possible.';   
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $status['type']     ='Error';
            $status['message']  ='Couldn\'t send the Email at this Time. Something went wrong';     
        }   

        // SIMPLY, RETURN THE JSON DATA...
 die(json_encode($status));
```

Here is my JS/AJAX:

```
   /***************** Contact Form Submission ******************/

$(document).ready(function (e){
$("#main-contact-form").on('submit',(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sendingemail').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
        url: "../sendemail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data.type == 'Error') {
                    //alert(data.message);
                  $('#sendingemail').fadeOut();
                  $("#notsent").html(data.message).fadeIn();
                }
            else{
                $('#sendingemail').fadeOut();
                $('#emailsent').fadeIn();
              //alert(data.message);
            }
        },
      error: function(XHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            //alert("error");
              console.log(XHR.status + "..." + textStatus + "..." + errorThrown);
              alert(XHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    }           
 );
}));
});
```

Comment: Can you explain "The echo alerts '200' and it then shows a parse error" What is the exact output and error?

Comment: whenever I try to use echo I get an alert that says '200' I click okay, then it shows 'parseerror' i click ok again and it then shows another alert that says 'unexpected token N in JSON  at position 0' I think I'm just using echo wrong.

Comment: These errors point to your using javascript somewhere - care to elaborate?

Comment: I just have some jquery code that takes the response from the PHP... anyways I removed the html lines and it seems to work without a telephone field. Not sure why the telephone field is breaking it.

Comment: The error has to do with the jquery. That is where you want to do your debugging. When you've worked out the error, I suspect it will work. Post the relavent jquery code if you need help. You might have to post a separate question.

Comment: @mseifert I added more php code (see the bottom of the php code) and the JS/AJAX

Comment: If you want continued help, you need to be clear in your communication which line of code is producing which message (you can edit you code if necessary to show this). It is not clear to me from your terminology which messages are from the js and which are from php. `alert` is always from js and `echo` is from php - the following doesn't make sense: `whenever I try to use echo I get an alert that says '200'`. You may need to add more debugging code to pin down where your issue resides.